# SwiftUI FoucsState with reusable styled textfield

Tags: swiftui, focus, textfield

I am having difficulties getting focusState to work when I'm using either a custom view or a TextFieldStyle.

I feel like what I'm trying to do should be incredibly simple - just a signup form, with styled inputs that passes the focus along to the next field - yet 2 days later, I'm still scratching my head! If I put all my elements into the main body, it works fine, but when I try to extract the common code to style the inputs, it fails.

Here's my latest attempt:

```
...
  @FocusState private var focusField: Field?
    enum Field : Hashable{
        case name, phone, email, password, referralCode
    }

   var body: some View {
        var name = Binding<String>(get: {
            viewModel.state.name
            
        }, set: { value in
            viewModel.onEvent(event: RegisterEventNameChanged(value: value))
            
        })
        var phone = Binding<String>(get: {
            viewModel.state.phone
        }, set: { value in
            viewModel.onEvent(event: RegisterEventPhoneChanged(value: value))
        })

  VStack(alignment: .leading){
                        
                        TextField(SharedRes.strings().label_full_name.desc().localized(), text: name)
                            .focused($focusField, equals: .name)
                            .onSubmit {
                                focusField = .phone
                            }
                            .textContentType(.name)
                            .disableAutocorrection(true)
                            .submitLabel(.next)
                            .textFieldStyle(SingleLineTextInput(
                                textValue: name,
                                errorValue: Binding(
                                    get: {viewModel.state.nameError  },
                                    set: {_ in  }
                                ),
                                label: SharedRes.strings().label_full_name.desc().localized()
                            ))
                        
                        TextField(SharedRes.strings().label_phone_number.desc().localized(), text: phone)
                        
                            .submitLabel(.done)
                            .keyboardType(.phonePad)
                            .focused($focusField, equals: .phone)
                            .onSubmit {
                                focusField = .email
                            }
                            .textFieldStyle(SingleLineTextInput(
                                textValue: phone,
                                errorValue: Binding(
                                    get: {viewModel.state.phoneError  },
                                    set: {_ in  }
                                ),
                                label: SharedRes.strings().label_phone_number.desc().localized()
                            ))
                    }.padding()
...
```

(If I comment out the  `.textFieldStyle(SingleLineTextInput(...` lines, focusState is working as expected (clicking next on name focuses phone), but with them there, the keyboard just dismisses when I press next from the name field)

Here's the textFieldStyle

```
struct SingleLineTextInput: TextFieldStyle {
    @Binding var textValue: String
    @Binding var errorValue: String?
    var label: String
  
    func _body(configuration: TextField<Self._Label>) -> some View {
        if (!textValue.isEmpty) {
            Text(label)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding(.bottom,-10)
        }
     configuration
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .frame(height: 40)
        .textInputAutocapitalization(.words)
                
        Rectangle()
            .frame(height:1)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .padding(.bottom,errorValue == nil ? 10 : 0 )
        if(errorValue != nil){
            Text(errorValue!)
                .font(.footnote)
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .padding(.bottom,10)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Underscore at  the beginning of apple code usually means undocumented `class`, `struct` or `func`. They aren't safe to use. Apple has not provided a documented way to create a `TextFieldStyle` maybe in a couple of weeks but nothing as of now.